# Need Regex to catch IPs excluding loopback

Tags: regex

I want to find all ip addresses in a file. The problem is that I need to exclude 127.0.0.1 address. I'm using grep in linux bash.
Here is what I have already:

```
[0-9]+.\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What regex flavor are you using ? Also note that you need to escape the dots. Hint: use a negative lookahead.

Comment: @HamZa He has shown us what he has tried.

Comment: What language are you using it in?

Comment: Is it too much trouble to simply say `if not equal to 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: if using something like grep  ` | grep -v 127.0.0.1`  at the end, to remove them.

Comment: @arshajii He showed us what he had, not what he tried to get the desired results.

Comment: @HamZa I don't understand what you mean. He is asking for a regex, and he showed us what regex he already attempted to use. What more should he have added?

Comment: @arshajii My point is that he already have a regex to match an IP address. But that's not the point of this question. The point is to also exclude a specific address. Did he try to solve this point ? No. Also as a side note, it may get quite complicated since `127.0.0.127` is also a valid loopback address.

Comment: It is utmost important to tell upfront what language/tool is being used for regex since that will vary the answers a lot.

Comment: I'll add that his rx will accept `1111.1.1.1`, because he used the `+` quantifier, and that `127.000.000.001` is equivalent to `127.0.0.1`, making a little more complex than a standard string comparison.

Comment: @xanatos lol what about the range `0,255` ? Hey and IPv6 !

Comment: I am using grep in linux bash

Comment: The problem of excluding 127.*.*.* is that the original text has some other stuff more than IP addresses. I didn't want to get it in two passes.(first exclude lo then find IP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
^(?!127\.0{1,3}\.0{1,3}\.0{0,2}1$)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Test http://regexr.com/3g3ov

I have changed the quantifiers to `{1,3}`.

The `(?!127\.0{1,3}\.0{1,3}\.0{0,2}1$)` means that you mustn't have a `127.0.0.1` (eventually padded with some `0`)

The `((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}` is for the first three digit groups with their `.`, `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` is for the last digit group.

And I have anchored the regex to the beginning `^` and ending `$` of the string.

If you want to exclude all the loopbacks (so `127.*.*.*`)

```
^(?!127)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Test http://regexr.com/3g3os

The two regexes are based on the regex from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html minus the parts about non-capturing groups.

Here I have to test only that the first group of digits aren't `127` (`(?!127)`)

This regex is complete, and it won't accept things like `256.256.256.256`, but it's only for IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all subnet 127.0.0.0/8 is reserved for loopbacks (so, 127.45.78.32 is also an address of loopback). Therefore, to solve your question via regexp it's needed to check first, that input string is not matching:

```
^127\.
```

and then check if it matches normal IP regex.